# Default sort-ordering in MySQL (ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY ...;)

Tags: mysql, sorting, alter-table

Assume that the default ordering of a MySQL-table (ISAM) is changed by executing:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY columnname ASC;
```

From now on, am I **guaranteed** to obtain records retrieved from the table in the order of "columnname ASC" assuming no "ORDER BY" is specified in my queries (i.e. "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ... LIMIT 10;")?

Are there any corner-cases that I should be aware of?

**Update #1:** Thanks a lot to Quassnoi who correctly pointed out that INSERTs and DELETEs messes up the ordering. This leads me to the following to extra questions:

- What about UPDATEs? Assume that no INSERTs or DELETEs are made to the table, but only updates - will the sort order be intact?
- Assume that INSERTs and DELETEs are made - how do I "rebuild" the sorting again, say once a day (in this specific case the table only changes daily, so rebuilding it daily after the changes are done should still be OK!). Does REPAIR TABLE fix it, or must add do ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY again?

Comment: Default sort ordering seems like an attempt at being lazy that will end up giving you tons of headaches down the road. I wouldn't touch it at all and would just make sure to specify Order By in my queries.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

> Note that the table does not remain in this order after inserts and deletes

Actually, if you issue `SELECT ... ORDER BY` to this table, the option to `ALTER TABLE` won't spare you of `filesort`, but instead make `filesort` much faster.

Sorting an already ordered set is equivalent to browsing this set to ensure everything is OK.

> What about UPDATEs? Assume that no INSERTs or DELETEs are made to the table, but only updates - will the sort order be intact?

If your table does not contain any dynamic fields (like `VARCHAR` or 'BLOB'), then *most probably* `MyISAM` will not move it when updating.

**I would not rely on this behavior, though, if I were building a nuclear power plant or something I get paid for.**

> Assume that INSERTs and DELETEs are made - how do I "rebuild" the sorting again, say once a day (in this specific case the table only changes daily, so rebuilding it daily after the changes are done should still be OK!). Does REPAIR TABLE fix it, or must add do ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY again?

You'll need to do `ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY`.

`REPAIR` just fixes the physical structure of a corrupted table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I've added two follow-up questions that are related to your answers.

Comment: @Quassnoi i did ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY and then deleted some records, my table didnt massed up.. ? why is that?

Comment: @Quassnoi hmm i thought maybe on 5.0 they have changed this and you would know about it.

Comment: @Basit: `5.0` was out in `2006`. Anyway, please post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

Physically ordering a column can save loads of IO.
It's perfectly legitimate method used in advanced systems to speed query time.
You just need to reorg the data every now and then so its stays clustered.
Just because some folks haven't heard of it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.
- 25 year advanced DB design veteran.