# MySQL default order depends on WHERE

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default sort-ordering in MySQL (ALTER TABLE … ORDER BY …;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725717/default-sort-ordering-in-mysql-alter-table-order-by)

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_test` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` enum('AF','AX','AL') DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort_order` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `country` (`country`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`country`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have a table for which I changed the default ordering like:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ORDER BY sort_order ASC;
```

This table is never updated and no records are removed or added during its life. This all seems to work so if I use the folowwing query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table LIMIT 10
```

It returns the 10 records in the right order.

And even if I use:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE num=3
```

it returns the results in the right order.

But if I do

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE country='AX'
```

It will return the results in reversed order.

Can someone tell me how this can happen?

Comment: `country` is indexed and maybe the `country` index is not in the same order as `sort_order`, or it isn't ordered at all. Or in your case it is accidentally reverse ordered...

Comment: _ORDER BY does not make sense for InnoDB tables that contain a user-defined clustered index (PRIMARY KEY or NOT NULL UNIQUE index). InnoDB always orders table rows according to such an index if one is present._ - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html - I know your table engine is MEMORY, yet I think the case is the same.

Comment: This appears to be similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725717/default-sort-ordering-in-mysql-alter-table-order-by.. except from docs: Note that the table does not remain in this order after inserts and deletes. This option is useful primarily when you know that you are mostly to query the rows in a certain order most of the time. By using this option after major changes to the table, you might be able to get higher performance. In some cases, it might make sorting easier for MySQL if the table is in order by the column that you want to order it by later...  Might, May... don't rely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying the ORDER BY on a table is just a help for the engine to speed up queries with the same order. It will not force mysql to always return the result with the same ordering.

Described in this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

"ORDER BY enables you to create the new table with the rows in a specific order. Note that the table does not remain in this order after inserts and deletes. This option is useful primarily when you know that you are mostly to query the rows in a certain order most of the time. By using this option after major changes to the table, you might be able to get higher performance. In some cases, it might make sorting easier for MySQL if the table is in order by the column that you want to order it by later. "

So you must use the ORDER BY expression in your queries too.

Comment: +1 And in case it's not clear enough: the concept of *default order* does not exist in the SQL language. It's intentional and by design.

Comment: IMO Better answer since it sites doc's references them and indicates outright to add order by to all queries.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why it happens. I don't want to know if it's the prefered way to do it but I need to know why the engine decides to reverse the sorting order. Besides, the documentation does not state that I should use ORDER BY in the query

Answer (score 3):

I guess the default order of your index on country is DESC. Because of this, if this one is used you get the "wrong" Order and in all other cases it is different. Not sure if or how it is possible to specify the order of the index in mysql, but i think it is.

But still im not sure if you can rely on the order if you dont specify one. Just add the ORDER BY statement to all your queries.

Comment: `Just add the ORDER BY statement to all your queries.` This is the correct answer. SQL **never** guarantees any particular ordering of the result set unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause. It does not matter what order the rows are physically stored in the table.

Comment: And MySQL does **not** have `DESC` indexes.

Answer (score 1):

why not you try the query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM test_table  ORDER BY sort_order ASC LIMIT 10;
SELECT * FROM test_table  WHERE num=3 ORDER BY sort_order ASC;
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE country='AX' ORDER BY sort_order ASC;
```

Comment: because that's not the question.  question is why does MYSQL have a feature on tables allowing a default order if it doesn't work. (or why isn't it working in their implementation

Comment: well as much i know order by should work on result set . I heard 1st time that you can do order by in alter statement. I am trying to read about it if i get solution than i will let u know..

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you see this behaviour is probably as follows: because the `WHERE` clause filters by `country`, MySQL uses the index on `country` to find the rows to be returned. Most likely the index rows are stored sorted by `country`, then by `id` (the primary key of the table). This means that the most efficient way for MySQL to retrieve the rows is by reading the rows referenced by the index, in the order they appear in the index. The order that the rows appear on disk is therefore irrelevant.

MySQL does provide syntax allowing you to specify the order of an index, but [this is currently ignored](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

*An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.*

You will have to add `ORDER BY` clauses to your queries in order to guarantee that the rows are returned in the desired order. Incidentally, this is always the case anyway; SQL makes no guarantee that rows will be returned in any particular order, regardless of how the rows are physically stored (unless an `ORDER BY` clause is present).

Comment: If this was the case it should show the sort_order in random order but it shows it perfectly in DESC order.

Comment: Just because it's not in the order you want it doesn't mean it's in *random* order. It's in whatever order MySQL finds it most convenient to show them to you. When the table is arranged with the rows in DESC order it just so happens that that order coincides with the order you want.