# Insert the new record after a exsiting result

Tags: mysql, insert

In my `items` table I got following records:

```
shop_vnum   item_vnum   count
4           13209       1
4           11229       1
```

And then, I want to insert a new record after `item_vnum` `13209` so it will look like:

```
shop_vnum   item_vnum   count
4           13209       1
4           12400       1
4           11229       1
```

Is that possible?

Comment: @EmCo You've just made me happy :S.

Comment: But you can insert it in a normal way and when you query the database, you can order the result by `item_vnum`. That might help.

Comment: What do you mean by inserting the new record "after" another? There's no concept of order in the data until you apply an ORDER BY clause on a SELECT.

Comment: @EmCo Thats might help, but not in my case because the query is executing by an application that I don't have a source to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an InnoDB table and item_vnum is a primary key, InnoDB will actually "physically" arrange the rows in an ascending order by item_vnum (this uses something called clustered indexes).

But, it looks like you are wanting it to be arranged in descending order, so the next best thing I can think of is creating a view:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-views/

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_MySQL_Views

```
CREATE VIEW items_view AS SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY item_vnum DESC;
```

Then, the view called "items_view" should behave like a table and reflect what you are looking for whenever you insert something into the "items" table.

But, the best answer is probably: You don't need to worry about how they are inserted. You only need to worry about how they are retrieved with your select statement later on. Be sure to use "ORDER BY item_vnum desc" at the end of your select statement.

Comment: dun try to use ORDER BY - see this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488588/mysql-default-order-depends-on-where

Answer (score 0):

Just like this

```
insert into items (shop_vnum, item_vnum, `count`)
values (4, 12400, 1);
```

Comment: Guy's asking to insert them in an order that isn't in the table. This would put it whereevere the DBengine felt was convenient.

Comment: if you dun understand, I dun blame you

Comment: Well seems to need the above row to be second in the selection without an order by, which is 'erm difficult

Comment: **FROM HEAD TO TOE I DUN SEE ORDER IS BEING MENTIONED** (sorry, for bold, uppercase)

Comment: Sigh. "And then, I want to insert a new record after item_vnum 13209 so it will look like:"

Comment: Which is correct! After I insert the record, I can 100% get back the same order **IF** using the order :)