# MYSQL, PHP, order by not working, primary key

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am generating a mySQL query from PHP.

Part of the query re-orders a table based on some variables (which do not include the primary key).

The code doesn't produce errors, however the table is not sorted.

I echo'd out the SQL code, and it looks correct, I tried running it directly in `phpMyAdmin`, and it runs also without error, but the table is still not sorted as requested.

```
alter table anavar order by dset_name, var_id;
```

I am pretty sure that this has to do with the fact that I have a primary key variable (UID) which is not present in the sort.

Both prior and post running the query the table remains ordered by UID. Deleting UID and re-running the query results in a correctly sorted table, but this seems like an overkill solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"but the table is not sorted as requested"* - There isn't any code to support the question, and none to support the php tag.

Comment: This may help, in fact it might be a obvious duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725717/default-sort-ordering-in-mysql-alter-table-order-by

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear. The MYSQL code appears correct to me (though I could be wrong) I didn't see the point in pasting the php code which generates the mysql, since running the mysql in phpmyadmin also has the same result. I can do if you think it's useful. To rephrase my question, should it be posisble to order by a variable other than the primary key? And if it is qhat could possibly be happening to prevent that working succesfully, thanks for the help.

Comment: If it functions the same in PHP and on the DB it is not a PHP issue.

Comment: Is the table in question MYISAM or INNODB?

Comment: You do realise you still have to use an ORDER BY in your query, all this does is reduce the necessary sorting that MYSQL has to do to generate your ORDERED query result

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's INNODB.

Comment: ___From the manual___  **ORDER BY does not make sense for InnoDB tables because InnoDB always orders table rows according to the clustered index.**

Comment: `alter table order by` is for the creation of a new table. Like, table #2. I think the engine is just ignoring what you are sending it

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are saying that a table has a physical order. But you can always query the resultset in a different order

Comment: I've tried chaning to MYISAM, but still having the same problem.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3681

Comment: looks like it is a bug ^

Comment: @Drew, thanks for the info. If I understand the log correctly, as long as I try to order by a single variable only, it should work? I've just tried that and have the same problem, i.e. the table remains sorted by the primary key and not by the variable in the order by clause.

Comment: @Drew yea I found that bug report, but its for MYSQL5.0

Comment: I am not sure why you are saying `variable`, and you really aren't showing us anything to allow us to help you

Comment: sorry, i meant column i come from a stats background, new to mysql.

Comment: just create a table, add data to it. Maybe call `create index` later. Do that for an hour. and do a select with various `order by` clauses. Play with that. And avoid `alter table` for a few weeks

Comment: Look at this silly table I made for this guy [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39318505). Now ignore my select stmt for starters

Comment: You could take that table called `t1` and run about 3 or 4 different permutations of `order by` on it

Comment: OK, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: create table mytab(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   dset VARCHAR(100) ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
insert into mytab (dset) values ("C"), ("B"), ("A");
alter table mytab order by dset;

Comment: Here is a bit more detail, hopefully that helps to explain my problem. I would expect this to re-order mytab so that it sorts according to the DSET column, but instead it remains sorted by the primary key?

Comment: do not screw around with `alter table` at this stage of what you are doing

Comment: just change the `order by` clause in a select stmt

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I don't think I can rely on select in this instance, though please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm dynamically creating a form which shows the contents of an sql table. I would like to give the users the ability to change the order of the records in the table, to do this I have some code to enable them to incrememnt one of the ordering columns and then run the alter table order by query. So I don't think a select statement would work in this instance, unless you are suggesting I  should create a new table (with the same name as the old table)

Comment: just leave your table alone. Forget their is a re-ordering `alter table` ,,, `let me restructure my physical ordering on the fly` ... no one does that. If you have 42M rows are you going to do that? I have never heard of that even being in there

Comment: What you need to do is to write a query for ranking on the fly. You determine the criteria and the query brings it back. The data is left alone in is native clustered ordering / physical ordering always. And you rely on secondary indexes to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    someInt int not null,
    thing varchar(100) not null,
    theWhen datetime not null,
    key(theWhen) -- creates an index on theWhen
);
-- my table now has 2 indexes on it 
-- see it by running `show indexes from t2`

-- truncate table t2;
insert t2(someInt,thing,theWhen) values
(17,'chopstick','2016-05-08 13:00:00'),
(14,'alligator','2016-05-01'),
(11,'snail','2016-07-08 19:00:00');

select * from t2; -- returns in physical order (the primary key `id`)
select * from t2 order by thing; -- returns via thing, which has no index anyway
select * from t2 order by theWhen,thing; -- partial index use

note that indexes aren't even used until you have a significant number of rows in a db anyway
```

### Edit (new data comes in)

```
insert t2 (someInt,thing,theWhen) values (777,'apple',now());

select t2.id,t2.thing,t2.theWhen,@rnk:=@rnk+1 as rank  
from t2 
cross join (select @rnk:=0) xParams 
order by thing; 
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+
| id | thing     | theWhen             | rank |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+
|  2 | alligator | 2016-05-01 00:00:00 |    1 |
|  4 | apple     | 2016-09-04 15:04:50 |    2 |
|  1 | chopstick | 2016-05-08 13:00:00 |    3 |
|  3 | snail     | 2016-07-08 19:00:00 |    4 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+
```

Focus on the fact that you can maintain your secondary indices and generate a `rank` on the fly whenever you want.