# PHP - Insert then Sort into mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have an html form where you can enter data that will update a mysql table via php. What I would like to do is after the insert is done the table to sort not by the ID but by the column Vendor. Is this possible?

```
    // Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$vendor = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['vendor']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO vendors (vendor) VALUES ('$vendor')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: You usually apply a sorting when you _read_ values from the table. I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: Although these two questions might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824928/how-to-sort-a-mysql-table-in-a-permanent-way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725717/default-sort-ordering-in-mysql-alter-table-order-by